# Why is my program not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple program to calculate the biggest even number from an array.

An array of 10 elements is used.

```js
function biggestEven(array) {       
  var numberOfNumbers = array.length;
  var biggestYet = 0;
  var theNumber;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i++) {
    if(array[i] % 2 = 0) {
      biggestYet = array[i];
    } 
    if(array[i] % 2 = 0 && array[i] > biggestYet) {
      theNumber = biggestYet;
    }
  }
  return theNumber;
}
var myArray = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
  myArray[i] = window.prompt("Enter number " + (i+1) + "of 10:"); 
}
console.log("The biggest even number is: " + biggestEven(myArray));
```

Please help I am stuck. The program won't lead in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You're giving a value, not comparing:

```
if(array[i] % 2 = 0) {
  biggestYet = array[i];
}
```

And also you were returning the wrong element:

```js
function biggestEven(array) { 
  var numberOfNumbers = array.length;
  var biggestYet = 0;
  var theNumber = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      biggestYet = array[i];
    }
    
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0 && array[i] > biggestYet) {
      theNumber = biggestYet;
    }
  }
  return biggestYet;
}

var myArray = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {    
  myArray[i] = window.prompt("Enter number " + (i+1) + " of 10:"); 
}

console.log("The biggest even number is: " + biggestEven(myArray));
```

This might help:

```js
console.log(Math.max(...[267, 306, 108, 307].filter(function(value) { return value % 2 === 0 })));
```

Comment: You're half way. Please show what's wrong and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
if(array[i] % 2 = 0) {
  biggestYet = array[i];
}
```

to

```
if(array[i] % 2 == 0) {
  biggestYet = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem

```js
    function biggestEven(array) { 
     return Math.max(...array.filter(function(num){
        return num%2==0;
      }));
    }
    var myArray = [1,2,36,45,51,16,7];
    alert(biggestEven(myArray));
```